# What programming language is used for mail servers?

Tags: email

I'm curious what programming language I would have to learn in order to create my own mail server. I'm not looking to compete with the big names, simply playing around.

For example, gmail, yahoo, msn. To be able to dynamically add @domain.com emails and allow users to check and send emails.

Comment: People should stop thinking that certain languages are used to build certain software. It's just a programming language. You can create a website in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail servers can be written in pretty much anything. Usually the bigger ones (sendmail/exim) are c/c++ but, you can pretty much write one in anything you choose. Its all a big text conversation if you look at how SMTP works.

Comment: can it be done via PHP on the web?

Comment: You could probably do it with php command line if you tried hard enough, it needs to run and listen on a port, so either it needs to be triggered for each port connection, or, constantly running.

Comment: Although someone may wish to use PHP for that, keep in mind that real world mail server has much more things to do that just listen to a connection on a port. The main problem it is a long running process and php was never designed no has built in tools for handling this tasks. PHP was always meant for short-timed tasks like producing HTML page, processing user input, etc. It may change in the future, but as of today it is so.